# How can I check if there is an instance running for a certain block of code in Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to know if it is possible to detect that a thread is already running a Cloud Functions, and if possible to also detect if it is running on a particular ID's data. I think I could have a variable stored in firebase memory of the ID in Firebase Database that the function is being run on from the Database, and to remove the variable when the function is done running,but the concern is of two writes to the database happening subsequently and very rapidly, causing the initial thread to not be able to write to memory fast enough before the second thread checks if the variable is there, especially on a cold start from the firebase thread - which in my understanding is a variable amount of time in which either thread could potentially spin up first.

My use case is this:

Let's say a write to the realtime database happens from the client side that causes a trigger for Cloud Functions to run a handler. This handlers job is to loop through and do work with the snapshot of records that was just written to by the client, and using a loop will parse each record in the snapshot, and when it is done, delete them. The handler works great until another record is written to the same group of records in the database before the handler's job is done, which causes a second handler thread to spin up, and start moving through the records in the same group of records, which would cause records to be iterated over twice, and possibly the data to be handled twice.

I have other solutions for my particular case which I can use instead, but it involves just allowing each record to trigger a separate thread like normal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is this file?  How is both the client and server able to deal with it concurrently?

Comment: The 'file' is just a snapshot of a group of records. Post was edited

Comment: You might want to use a push to generate a unique id, then insert the batch of data atomically there.  A function watching that location will only be executed once.

Comment: I'm not certain where you mean to insert the batch of data. The data from the snapshot I am using is taking records in pairs from the snapshot and parsing them to create a separate chunk of data. All the pairs are relative to eachother, so I need to basically have the function execute every other time which is not an issue, but my main question is if is possible to stop another thread from spinning up to handle the same data that is already being processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to track running instances "in-memory" for Cloud Functions, as each function invocation may be running in entirely different virtual infra. Instead, what you'd most likely want to do here is have some kind of lock persisted in e.g. the Firebase Realtime Database [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction). So you'd do something like:

1. When the function invocation starts, generate a random "worker ID".
2. Run a transaction to check a DB path derived from the file you're processing. If it's empty, or populated with a timestamp that is older than a function timeout, write your worker ID and the current timestamp to the location. If it's not empty or the timestamp is fresh, exit your function immediately because there's already an active worker.
3. Do your file processing.
4. Run another transaction that deletes the lock from the DB if the worker ID in the DB still matches your worker ID.

This will prevent two functions from processing the same file at the same time. It will mean, however, that any functions that execute while a path is locked will be discarded (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: I really like your answer, and a lock is exactly what I was trying to find the other day similar to the lock method in c#, so thank you for that. And you know, I was trying to think of any faults for your answer, but I can't foresee anything yet. Fantastic answer. I'll mull it over and mark it if I can't find any issues.

Comment: What would be the best route to determine if a separate transaction was attempted and discarded, meaning that another record was written? I can imagine that the discarded worker would first write to the database indicating with a boolean that another record was added so that the initial worker can reevaluate the newly added log, but my concern is that as the second stopped transaction is writing to the database, the first worker transaction would have already checked the boolean in the small timeframe and began the steps to shut down.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to detect "worker death" in this way because by definition the worker has died. One way to go about it would be to have the worker continuously update a "lastAliveAt" timestamp (e.g. every 500ms) and have the second worker check that lastAliveAt was very recent before abandoning.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I've come up with an alternative solution that I'll implement for this, but it seems that there will just be a very small margin for error in that sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hey @MichaelBleigh, so just putting a little more thought into your system. When I check if there is a timestamp populated that is older than the transactions designated timeout, what is the point? Wouldn't I just have the transaction restart itself and create a new timestamp if it went past the timeout, and any other newly created transactions would just check if there was a current worker ID? Thanks for any clarification, I don't work with timestamp based concurrency systems enough.

Comment: The idea is that if the function gets killed or crashes for an unknown reason in the middle of execution, you can tell because there will be a stale timestamp. It will allow you to implement a way to "kick over" stuck tasks by doing a write that re-triggers the function.

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense. Thank you for your answers, they've been really helpful. I'll pour some more time into researching timestamp systems as well.

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for cloud functions, currently I am using firebase queue on heroku and setting numWorkers = 1, actually its a headace to deploy to heroku and cloud functions, so I am also thinking of wrapping my firebase queue inside a cloud functions (with numWorkers =1) I believe firebase queue is stable and handle all special cases above, what do yo think? said in the docs that "Multiple queue workers can be initialized on multiple machines and Firebase-Queue will ensure that only one worker is processing a single queue task at a time."